# Symfony2: how to log query duration to logs/dev.log

Tags: php, symfony, logging, doctrine-orm

In dev env Symfony2 logs SQL queries to dev.log by default. For profiling and debugging purposes I'd like to log a query's **execution time** as well. This must be possible since the "real page"'s profiler shows the execution times next to each query. I think the correct class is the [DBalLogger](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Logger/DbalLogger.php) + a stopwatch instance but I don't know how and where I configure those services correctly (monolog? doctrine? dbal.connection? [samples say](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/symfony/logging-doctrine-queries-in-symfony2/) we have to use setSQLLogger but where can I do that in my config_dev.yml?)

Answer (score 1):

you could inject the monolog service and then manually add a time reference

```
$logger = $this->get('logger');
$timestart = microtime(true);
// Your query goes here
$timeend = microtime(true);
$logger->info("Query time: " . (($timeend - $timestart) * 1000) . "s");
```

Comment: sure, but I'd like to do that for *every* query, automatically :)

Comment: you could extend the method its class and then adjust it where necessary

Comment: BTW @MaximGeerinck microtime already returns time in seconds, you do not need to use * 1000. microtime returns time with microseconds not in microseconds

Comment: Correct, the `true` makes it returns in seconds, thus `*1000` will result in the microseconds